# Migrate all work items with history, attachments, links from TFS Kanban to Azure boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there any way we can migrate all the workitems with history and having attachments ,links and Test cases
from TFS Kanban to Azure boards ?

Your response would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) extension.

[image]

The Azure DevOps Migration Tools allow you to bulk edit and migrate data between Team Projects on both Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Azure DevOps Services. Take a look at the [documentation](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) to find out how.

Here is a blog about [TFS 2017 Migration To VSTS with VSTS Sync Migrator from Mohamed Radwan](https://mohamedradwan.com/2017/09/15/tfs-2017-migration-to-vsts-with-vsts-sync-migrator/), you can follow its guidance.